How do you separate premises in logic?
In logic, you are tasked to identify the premise and conclusion of an argument, I personally find that very straight forward. However, when writing these arguments in standard form people separate the premises. Take for example this,
"Since private property helps people define themselves, since it frees people from mundane cares of daily subsistence, and since it is finite, no individual should accumulate so much property that others are prevented from accumulating he necessities of life."
This then gets convert to this
P1: Since private property helps people define themselves
P2: Since it frees people from mundane cares of daily subsistence
P3: and since it is finite
C: no individual should accumulate so much property that others are prevented from accumulating the necessities of life.
It is fine to just write or is this wrong? If so, how do you separate the premises from each other because they could be dependent clauses that need to have an independent clause to exist and it doesn't necessarily make sense without it yet we still separate it and consider it as another premise.
P: Since private property helps people define themselves, since it frees people from mundane cares of daily subsistence, and since it is finite.

Rewrite them as stand-alone sentences:"Private property helps people define themselves." Etc

Lewis Carroll's The Game of Logic may be helpful in teaching you how to analyze this and rewrite the argument in a form that makes it easier to see what the premisses and conclusion are and to decide if the argument is logically valid and overall sound (valid and believable).
The main thing is that an argument is a sequence of propositions. A proposition is a complete statement that can be either true or false, it's some assertion. The premisses are all the statements that are introduced without further argument. Some statements may be intermediate conclusions that follow from previous statements. The conclusion is just the last statement. Some premisses may be redundant for the argument (not needed to make the argument valid, irrelevant to reach the conclusion). The conclusion is "logically valid" if it "follows from" the preceding propositions.
There are various rules to determine whether or not the argument is valid. In everyday use, however, many arguments just use the modus ponens argument schema, with two premisses and a conclusion:

if p then q
p
(therefore) q

Example

If the moon is made of blue cheese then the moon is edible.
The moon is made of blue cheese.
Therefore, the moon is edible.

This is a valid argument, by modus ponens. Though it may not be sound since premisse 2 seems unlikely to be true.
You may still ask, "OK, so... why is modus ponens valid? I can see the argument follows that funny schema, but what does it mean to say this argument is 'logically valid'?" The answer to that is that a "valid" argument is a truth-preserving argument. The schema is a truth-preserving schema. In other words, the schema can be used as a valid logical rule because we can see that if all premisses are true (that is, if we replace the letters 'p' and 'q' by true statements), then the conclusion is also true.
In everyday language a word like "since" (or similar "therefore", "thus", "because") is a verbal marker to distinguish premisses from conclusions. Your example sentence has the overall schema of "Since p, since q, and since r, s". This can be rewritten as "(p and q and r) therefore s" or as "(p and q and r) implies s". So, the argument is

p and q and r  (premisse)
s (conclusion)

It can also be rewritten with three separate premisses as

p
q
r
s

It's clear that this argument, in this form is too silly to even be taken seriously, since there is no visible relation between the conclusion and the premisses ('s' doesn't occur in the premisses at all). So, the analysis needs to dig further into each of p, q, r, and s, take them apart, and see how they can be rewritten in such a way that it's clear from the presentation (the logical form) that the argument is either valid or invalid.
When figuring out the logical form or schema of an informal argument, you need to pay special attention to (on the one hand) words like "since", "therefore", which mark premisses versus conclusion, and (on the other hand) logical connectives ("and", "or", "if ... then ...", "not") and quantifier expressions ("all", "every", "no", "there is a", "there are no")
In everyday language the connectives are ambiguous, in a more formalized argument they may only be used as connectives between propositions (or applied to one proposition in the case of "not").

Jack and Jill are puppets

is analyzed as

(Jack is a puppet) and (Jill is a puppet)

which could be further rewritten as

There are x, y such that (x is not equal to y) and (x is a puppet) and (y is a puppet) and (x is named "Jack") and (y is named "Jill")

One extra complication in your example is that it uses a modal operator ("should", "ought"). It's not always necessary to explicitly represent this in order to decide if an argument is valid or invalid, but if needed, we can represent it as an operator that works on complete propositions. Exactly how to do this, can be rather tricky (see deontic modal logic if you're interested).
In your example

No individual should be allowed to_be_filthy_rich

could be represented as

For all x, if x is an individual, then it is not permitted to x that x is_filthy_rich

If the quantifiers are always restricted to human individuals, then this can be simplified to

For all x, it is not permitted to x that x is_filthy_rich

Which, by an intuitive rule of deontic logic could also be written as

For all x, it is obligatory to x that it is not so that x is_filthy_rich

Or, translated back into everyday language

Everyone ought to not be filthy rich (i.e. so rich that it prevents someone else from living at subsistence levels).


You ask:

How do you separate premises in logic?

Using the rules of natural language grammar intuitionally. Taking more complex grammatical constructions and through a combination of syntactical transformations and paraphrasing, you can rewrite your argument anyway you see fit, with the caveat that you MUST preserve the semantics. That is, you cannot alter the meaning, at least for the purposes of using logic to preserve truth from premises to conclusion. This is an art, because inevitably, syntactic changes and taking liberties by shortening constructions do change the semantics in some minor way at a minimum. For instance, moving from active to passive voice has a subtle effect on meaning.
Studying the dynamics of paraphrasing strengthens the ability to do it well. Just like any natural language skill, understanding the concepts surrounding improve your performance. From WP:

For the purposes of education, Fred Inglis identifies five levels of paraphrase:

replacing words with synonyms
varying sentence structure
reordering information
turning long sentences into multiple shorter ones (or vice versa)
expressing abstract concepts more concretely.


Thus, paraphrasing depends on a series of skill all of which can be honed.
This concept of paraphrasing is actually philosophically challenging and enters into a debate over the analytic/synthetic distinction. Quine famously in his Two Dogmas rejected the distinction and introduced the term cognitive synonymy where he calls into question the presumption that typical synonyms can be used without altering meaning. In fact, among contemporary linguists, the presumption is that any change in syntax highlights a change in semantics or pragmatics.

+1 "... paraphrasing ... is an art" can not be underlined too often.

@mudskipper So, right now, I am soaking up relevance theory where the central premise is, that communication is the use of intelligence to decide relevance in the context of shared intentionality, which butts up nicely with Tomasello's work on the origins of language. Paraphrasing in the context of erotetic logic which is the heart of the dialectic, as far as I can tell, is the only reliable measure of intelligence whatsoever. Everything else is detail.
